# How to give arguments to closeEvent()

Tags: python, pyqt5

I create a `GUI` using `Qt Designer`. Now I need to give extra arguments to `closeEvent`. How can I give extra parameters to `closeEvent`? The argument will be an instance of another window. So that I can use this instance as an argument in another function in closeEvent.
Below a simplified code.

```
class UiMain(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, subwindow):
        super(UiMain, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_UiArtikelkarte()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.show()

    def closeEvent(self, event, subwindow):
        some_function(self, source=subwindow)
        event.accept()


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
win1 = UiMain(subwindow)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This gives me of Course:

```
TypeError: closeEvent() missing 1 required positional argument: 'subwindow'
```

Any way to give extra arguments to `closeEvent`?
Help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you pass the extra argument to the constructor, maybe you can just save the data and display it on the `closeEvent` method.

```
class UiMain(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, test):
        super(UiMain, self).__init__()
        self.test = test
        self.ui = Ui_UiArtikelkarte()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.show()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        print(self.test)
        event.accept()


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
win1 = UiMain("hello")
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: That is right, but I want to reference instances of other windows as arguments. So lets say, that I want to reference "subwindow = SubWindow()" (also QtWidgets.QMainWindow). Sorry for not being clear. I will update my question right away.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to pass your subwindow as attribute :

```
class UiMain(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, subwindow):
        super(UiMain, self).__init__()
        self.subwindow = subwindow
        self.ui = Ui_UiArtikelkarte()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.show()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        some_function(self, source=self.subwindow)
        event.accept()


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
win1 = UiMain(subwindow)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am still a beginner in Python and I thought you couldn't make a reference like you did with "self.subwindow = subwindow". I thought for this is not possible for classes.